# Exception class EConvertError with message ''' is not a valid floating point value'.

Tags: delphi

Hey can anybody help me with this error please, I can't seem to find a solution.
Any help would be appreciated. 
I am working with Windows 8 and Delphi RAD Studio 2010.

If there are more errors then what I'm referring to please feel free to comment on them.

```
procedure TfrmStats.FormShow(Sender:      TObject);
begin
 // // Code that connects the     TADOConnection to the database
// //conDatabase.Close;
// conDatabase.ConnectionString :=        'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data    Source=E:\[Phase    2]\db_DatabaseStock.mdb;Persist Security    Info=False' ;
// conDatabase.Open;

// Code sets radiobutton.checked and   checkbox.checked to true to avoid errors   and
 // simplify GUI
 rb2D.Checked := True;
 chkShowLegend.Checked := True;

 // Code hides ShowGrid checkbox
 chkShowItemGrid.Visible := False;

 //Code hides Stringgrid
 SGStats.Visible := False;

     DrawPie;
     **end;**  // The breakpoint is here (Where delphi says the error is)
```

I will also show the code for the procedure being called:

```
procedure TfrmStats.DrawPie;
var
sSQL :string;
iRow, iCol, iA : Integer;
dblGT, dblLST, dblValue, PiePercentage : Double;
begin
 // Procedure used to draw the chart of data
 // Here call Subtotal
 SGstats.Cells[0,1] := 'Sub Total';
 SGstats.Cells[1,1] :=    IntToStr(GetSub);

 with qryItems do
 begin
 // Select itemname an populate the stringgrid
   SQL.Clear;
   sSQL := 'SELECT DISTINCT ItemName FROM tblItems ORDER BY ItemName';
   SQL.Add(sSQL);
   Open;
   Active := False;
   Active := True;

   if (RecordCount <> 0) then
   begin
     SGstats.RowCount := SGstats.RowCount + RecordCount;
     for iRow := 0 to RecordCount -1 do
     begin
       SGstats.Cells[0,iRow+2] :=   FieldByName('ItemName').AsString;
       Next;
     end;

   end;
 end;
 qryItems.Close;

  with qryItems do
 begin
 // Select itembookquantity and populate the stringgrid
   SQL.Clear;
       sSQL := 'SELECT DISTINCT ItemName, ItemBookQuantity FROM tblItems ORDER BY ItemName';
   SQL.Add(sSQL);
   Open;
   Active := False;
   Active := True;

   if (RecordCount <> 0) then
    begin
      SGstats.RowCount := SGstats.RowCount + RecordCount;
      for iRow := 0 to RecordCount -1 do
      begin
       SGstats.Cells[1,iRow+2] := FieldValues['ItemBookQuantity'];
       Next;
      end;
   end;
 end;

 // Code that actually draws piechart
 with chtStats do
 begin
   //Clear the charts series
   while (SeriesCount> 0) do
   Series[0].Free;

    //Change title
   Title.Text.Clear;
   Title.Text.Add('Items');

    // Add series to piechart
   AddSeries(TPieSeries.Create(Self));
   Series[0].Name := 'PieItems';

   for iRow := 2 to SGstats.RowCount -2      do
    begin
          PiePercentage :=     (StrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,iRow])/StrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,1]))*100;
         Series[0].Add(StrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,  iRow]), SGStats.Cells[0,iRow] + ', ' + FormatCurr('0.####',PiePercentage) + ' %', clteecolor);
       end;
     end;
```

The subtotal is supposed to be an integer. I'm also experiencing an 'Authentication Failed' error when running the program, any assistance would be appreciated. I'm still only a beginner so I may overlook small things or make simple mistakes :D

If I need to add more information to help, please let me know!

Comment: The IDE should break in DrawPie, probably on Series[0].Add(... Watch for an empty cell in SGstats. Use StrToFloatDef if necessary. In general, you should post a [mcve] when you want your code debugged by others. Better if you learn how to debug though..

Comment: The error message could hardly be clearer. Basic debugging would take you to the source of the problem. This is not how programming should be. You shouldn't expect to have to ask a question here every time you make a mistake. Debugging is a crucial skill that you must learn.

Comment: IOn the second code block you call `qryItems.Open`, then set `qryItem.Active := False`, followed by `qryItem.Active := Trtue`,. This opens the query (`.Open`), closes it (`.Active := False`),  then reopens using `Active := True`.   TDataSet.Open and TdataSet.Active := True  are equivalent statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear: you are trying to convert to float an empty string. Delphi raises an exception because an empty string doesn't represent any valid float value.

You need to first check that the strings that you are using are not empty, and decide what to do in that case : inform the user, draw an empty pie, ...

By the way, if you want to consider your empty strings as zeros, then you can code your own customized conversion function.

```
function CustomStrToFloat(string: variant): double;
begin
  if (string = null) or (Trim(string) = '') then Result := 0
  else Result := StrToFloat(string);  
end;
```

Please notice that this function will still raise an exception if your input is not an empty string (or a null variant), so the user will know that you are receiving inconsistent inputs.

Now you just have to change your code in order to use your customized conversion function

```
...
PiePercentage := (CustomStrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,iRow])/CustomStrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,1]))*100;
Series[0].Add(CustomStrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,  iRow]), SGStats.Cells[0,iRow] + ', ' + FormatCurr('0.####',PiePercentage) + ' %', clteecolor);
...
```

About the 'Authentication Failed' error, can you debug your code and check what line raises that error ?. Looks like that it's going to be when you execute your SQL query, in that case the credentials that you have defined on the connection object of your SQLQuery are not correct.

EDIT: As Remy Lebeau has suggested, Delphi already includes two functions to deal with conversions from strings not containing valid representations of floating values. The first one is StrToFloatDef (string to float with a default value for non-valid strings).

You will only need to change your code to :

```
...
PiePercentage := (StrToFloatDef(SGstats.Cells[1,iRow],0)/StrToFloatDef(SGstats.Cells[1,1],0))*100;
Series[0].Add(StrToFloatDef(SGstats.Cells[1,  iRow],0), SGStats.Cells[0,iRow] + ', ' + FormatCurr('0.####',PiePercentage) + ' %', clteecolor);
...
```

I don't use it because it will not only consider as zeros all the empty strings, but also every other string with inconsistent contents, and in those cases I prefer to let the program raise an exception, so the user is going to be notified that the input values are not valid.

The other function that you could use is TryStrToFloat, that is going to try to do the conversion and return true or false if the conversion has been successful.

If you use this, you will need to change those two lines to :

```
var FirstCell, SecondCell: extended;
...
...

FirstCell := 0;
SecondCell := 0;

if not TryStrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[0,iRow], FirstCell) then 
   ShowMessage('Input Values not valid');
if not TryStrToFloat(SGstats.Cells[1,iRow], SecondCell) then 
   ShowMessage('Input Values not valid');

PiePercentage := (SecondCell/FirstCell)*100;
Series[0].Add(SecondCell, SGStats.Cells[0,iRow] + ', ' + FormatCurr('0.####',PiePercentage) + ' %', clteecolor);
...
```

Comment: The RTL also has `StrToFloatDef()` and `TryStrToFloat()` functions. Checking for an empty string is not enough to catch all possible conversion errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, as previously mentioned I'm only a beginner and it's the first time I have encountered such an error and after searching the web for hours and going through my code, I finally decided to stop wasting time and ask for help. I am not familiar with debugging but will definitely educate myself about it later on. All my thanks to those with patience and those who provided the help I needed :)

Comment: @Suri: You can select the error in the message pane and press F1 to get help on the message. But the message is clear, IMO: an empty string is not a valid floating point value.